# Capture error and continue when inserting into a unique column

Tags: php, mysql, insert, unique

I have a unique column. The thing is, as I understand it, when you try to insert some data into that column that violates its uniqueness, the query will stop getting processed. What I wanna do is simply capture the error and continue with the rest of the rows. How would you do this in the most efficient way using PHP and MySQL?

here you have a short example
http://pastie.org/1357001

what i really was wondering is that will the loop get broken if an error occurs?

Comment: hmmm...the query will **NOT stop** getting processed unless you instruct PHP do so, code snippet?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Oh noes! Incoming SQL injection!

Comment: Your sample data is CSV, not excel

Comment: what does that got to do with anything ?

Comment: @elusive nah not really it for my own use making it easier for me to keep track of my clients so it's in a quite controlled enviroment

Comment: Came here for the same question, as how laravel handle slugs in the background. As i want to do same for my own application. No real solution given. Yet i not blame any of the answers. It all comes back to either personal knowledge (logic) or find a better answer. ( a shared answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to catch that error:

```
try {
    // execute SQL query for one record
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Comment: ah of course i was just afraid that the query would stop working if an error occured

Answer (score 2):

I'm with ajreal on this one.  Violating a constraint should not cause an exception in PHP.  You can just test the return value from [mysqli_stmt::execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php), or whatever it is that you are using, and deal with any errors that have occurred:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');

// Prepare an INSERT;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)');
$data = 'Some data';

// Insert 3 rows.
for ( $id = 1; $id <= 3 ; $id++ ) {

    // Attempt to insert each row twice.
    for ( $test = 1; $test <= 2; $test++ ) {

        // Bind the ID and data.
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $id, $data);

        // Execute the statement.
        if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
            // No error.
            echo "Inserted row ID $id\n";
        } else {
            // An error, but no exception.
            printf(
                "Error %d inserting row ID %d: %s\n",
                $stmt->errno,
                $id,
                $stmt->error
            );
        }
    }    
}
```

Prints:

```
Inserted row ID 1
Error 1062 inserting row ID 1: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Inserted row ID 2
Error 1062 inserting row ID 2: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
Inserted row ID 3
Error 1062 inserting row ID 3: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($somethings as $something)
{
    try
    {
       //mysql_query
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $failed[] = $e;
        continue;
    }

    //process anything else.
}
```

Exceptions are the way to go.