# Android : code to deal when insert a value 2nd time into a unique column

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, unique

I googled it for hours but found no result. Wondering how nobody getting into my problem.
I have SQLite table with a UNIQUE column and I have to insert values to it. When insert a value second time into that column, I want it to pop up error so that I can generate other value to insert again. Here is the pseudocode of what I want:

> returnCode = db.insert(value);
>
> while((returnCode == -1) && (getErrorCode() == DOUBLE_VALUE_IN_UNIQUE_COLUMN))
>
> {
>
> ```
>     otherValue = generate();
>
>     returnCode =db.insert(otherValue);
> ```
>
> }

I already found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381644/capture-error-and-continue-when-inserting-into-a-unique-column) on the site but the answer is for PHP and also not what I want.  Now the question is how to do it in Android or are there such a mechanism like that(like "getErrorCode() == DOUBLE_VALUE_IN_UNIQUE_COLUMN")? Real Java code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [db.insertOrThrow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), catch the Exception if any and do whatever you want to do when it happens.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but as I mention, I want to deal with unique collumn. So which Exception inform that I insert double value to that unique collumn. If it is other kind of exception, I will not deal with it.

Comment: Please help. I need it very much.

Comment: Have you tried my tip? Which Exception did you receive in one case and the other?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your tip and get this error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed. So the mechanism I want is impossible? If that is, I wonder what is the standard or common way to insert value into unique collumn. Can someone recommend that way?

Comment: Hi, I still find noway to deal with unique column. Is there any standard or best practice to insert data into unique column or is there a way so that if we insert double value, we can try other value again infinite time?

Comment: Hello, anybody there? Please help or show your way to solve it. I still stuck at this point.

Comment: One week and I still cannot touch this 'insert' part in my app. Any body there, help!